# What does CWOP mean on visa cancelled stamp?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration

I was traveling to Dubai on a tourist visa. I was stopped by Immigration and my visa was cancelled; they also wrote CWOP on the stamp.

Will this cause problems the next time I travel?

Comment: Can you tell us why you think immigration canceled it? Insufficient funds, background, ...?

Answer (score 28):

[Canceled without prejudice](http://www.immihelp.com/forum/showthread.php/26273-What-is-quot-CWOP-quot-on-the-passport-stamped-mean)

It means the visa was canceled, but cancellation does not affect future applications and issuance of visas.

From the [US State Department Glossary definition](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/glossary.html#C) (thanks to @richardb):

> **Cancelled Without Prejudice:** A stamp a U.S. Embassy or Consulate puts
>   on a visa when there is a mistake in the visa or the visa is a
>   duplicate visa (two of the same kind). It does not affect the validity
>   of other visas in the passport. It does not mean that the passport
>   holder will not get another visa.

Comment: "Without prejudice" is a legal term of art that more or less means "You can apply again in the future as if this never happened". Judges often dismiss lawsuits "Without prejudice" for irregularities like filing in the wrong court or not using the new cover sheet for a TPS report. Lawsuits that are completely without merit or are outright unlawful are more appropriately dismissed "with prejudice", meaning that the filer isn't allowed to try again.

Comment: Is it just me or nobody cares to notice that the reference provided in this answer is weak at best? It is just another forum with 2 random people talking to each other about the same problem and providing the same answer. Please consider improving it by providing some credible reference to your already correct answer.

Comment: @HankyPanky I tried looking for this myself. Searching "CWOP visa", the first 5 pages are all people who had their visa CWOP stamped and were wondering what it meant. The only thing i could find that mentioned CWOP in a different context was something from the Ohio State University, in an article about international scholars.

Comment: The US State Department has it in its [glossary](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/glossary.html#C)

Comment: Thanks @richardb, added that to my answer as another source.

Comment: The US State Dept. definition only says that the holder is not barred from getting another visa; it does not say that the cancellation will not be taken into account when deciding future applications.

Comment: @fkraiem but based on the definition of "prejudice" found in a legal dictionary (for example, "injury or detriment to one's legal rights or claims") the term does in fact mean that the cancellation will not adversely affect the bearer's future applications.