# What does it mean when an immigration officer puts a CWOP on passport?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, dubai

I was traveling to Dubai but due to health issue I got off the flight but immigration officer put a CWOP stamp on my passport. I googled about it and it is showing that it refers to visa cancellation but he didn't tell me anything about my visa.

When I checked about my visa validity on Dubai's official site it is showing valid. I am traveling again to Dubai but I am unsure about my visa and this stamp.

Comment: When was this?  It might take a while for the portal to catch up.

Comment: See answer to [What does CWOP mean on visa cancelled stamp? - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88514/95267)

Comment: Where did they put the stamp? On/near the visa or on/near an exit stamp? Which country’s officer did put that stamp?

Comment: It’s definitely not obvious to me that the stamp is actually linked to the visa, given that OP mentions a visa for Dubai, but says they disembarked on their way to Dubai, so it would be an immigration officer from a different country who stamped CWOP, and they obviously wouldn’t be able to cancel a visa from another country. So most likely not a duplicate (but lacks clarity, pending updates from OP).

Comment: @jcaron It does, however, explains how **CWOP** (Cancelled Without Prejudice) is to generally understood.

Comment: Where did you get off the flight?  What country was the immigration officer who stamped your passport from?  Please edit your question with this information and, ideally, add an image of the passport page including the stamp, with any identifying information blacked out.